# Randomly generate strings based off an array and sort to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I cant figure out how to randomly generate the data stored in listbox1 and randomly sort it in the Datagridview.  I want all of this to be done through private void button3_Click.  The datagridview has 2 columns, Team 1 and Team 2. Both columns need the data from listbox1. Thanks

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string n = textBox1.Text;
        string n2 = textBox2.Text;
        string[] names = new string[] { n, n2 };


        IEnumerable<string> nameQuery =
            from name in names
            select name;


        foreach (string i in nameQuery)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add(i + " ");

        }


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }
}
```

}

Comment: How about showing a sample of your data and what you want the output to be?

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to accomplish by doing this.